# Is it possible to send an email after a new row is added to an SQL table

Tags: email, mariadb, sql-insert, database-trigger

I'm running MariaDB SQL server on Debian Linux, I have phpMyAdmin installed. SSMTP is installed and configured so I can send emails from the command line.

I have a simple table, called team_members, and every time a new team member is added to the table, a new row with unique ID is created, I would like to know how to send what has been added to the table as an email.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| nickname   | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| first_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| last_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| email      | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| timestamp  | timestamp    | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I understand that this is possible using a trigger, but I don't really understand how it works.

Could anyone possibly give me an example of how to achieve this.

This table is not going to be updated very often, maybe once a month, so its not going to cause lots of unwanted emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find away to do this so I used PHPMailer to email the content of the input form instead. Its not exactly 100% what I wanted to it works.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you cannot invoke any actions outside of MySQL from within MySQL.  So, no, you cannot send an email.

On the other hand, your application that does the `INSERT` could do some form of sendmail.